# auto indenting wrapped Python code in Word

Tags: python, ms-word, word-wrap, auto-indent

I'm wrestling with Microsoft Word to display my Python code correctly and am in need of some help.

I am trying to paste large amounts of Python scripts into Microsoft Word with documentation text written around the snippets. Some of these Python snippets are a few lines, others are over a page long. Since the document is now around 500 pages long there are around 200 snippet blocks scattered throughout the document.

I have a font style I created set to the snippets. So I can change font size, color, style etc for all of them at once. But I'm having a big problem with the word wrapping. Long statements in Python get wrapped in word which makes them hard to read since the indents are lost. I am able to successfully indent the level 1 wrapped line using "hanging indents". But I cannot do anything about a level 2 or level 3 indent since nested stuff is further indented.

Example (I've used dots instead of spaces because it kept removing them)

```
This is a statement
This is another statement
if (condition):
.........This is a third statement
.........This is a fourth statement
.........for loop : 
..................This is a fifth statement
..................This is a sixth statement
..................if (condition):
...........................This is a seventh statement
```

Imagine each statement is fairly long and gets wrapped to the next line on a word page. I get

```
This is a statement
This is another statement
if (condition):
.........This is a third     
statement
.........This is a fourth     
statement
.........for loop:
.................This is
a fifth statement
.................This is a
sixth statement
```

How can I fix this in word? A hanging indent will fix the level 1 indents (the statements in the if condition) but not the level 2 indents (the statements in the for loop)

Note: I would like to use some sort of option, or plugin or macro within word. I cannot use a code editor and copy and paste code in rtf or some other format. Even if I did this 200 times to replace all my code snippets, the moment I change the font size in my document everything will get messed up again. Another option would be some IDE that embeds or links into word (without having to copy and paste) and allows changes to font style and size in its own environment which will get updated at all occurrences in Word automatically.

Please help if you can. I have searched like crazy and found nothing that works...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the disadvantage to formatting as, say, HTML (via an online formatting tool) and then pasting into Word. Changing the font size after that should not cause any problems.

Comment: Use latex and the lstlistings package if you want to format code. Word is the hell. You should know by now. With latex, you can change any font size you want, your code is not going to move. Heck, you're programming Python, why are you even considering using Word still???

Comment: Well, I don't know how to force Word to not do linewraps so I can't help... But.. There is other thing I just want to point.. - why not code with PEP8 rules and make your codelines max 79 chars long - this should fit on the page and keep Word away from auto-wrapping

Comment: nmichaels, I was attempting to stick to word since all the other text is formatted exactly the way I need, font styles all set up, index generating itself etc, but if lyx will make tihs task much easier then I'll switch. I will look into lyx, it looks free and appears to be easier than learning latex. Thanks for this.

Comment: Joris, I will look into latex and lstlistings as well. nmichaels suggested lyx so that might be easier .. Ive never used latex. Word has done a great job with all the other stuff and the non-code text is associated with font styles that update the whole document when changed. I imagine latex can  do this too tho, so I will give latex a shot as you suggest.

Comment: tmg, I will look up PEP8. I was considering this (would have to make the change to all 200+ snippets manually). I was thinking that if I increased the font size at some point tho, those same statments would then no longer fit on one line and get wrapped without the indents. It is those indents that have given me a real hard time. If I cant get those to work tho (using latex, lyx as per other suggestions) I will go with your solution, its better than what I am doing now. Thanks

Comment: joaquin, that was a typo, I put too many dots, I have edited the original post and fixed

Comment: Votey, are you saying that HTML formatting sort of embeds html into the word document? So the indentation will remain constant even tho font sizes are changed? If so this will only require me to generate all snippets the first time and after that it will be low maintenance.. I will look into this, thank you

Comment: Doesn't Word have an as-is or pre-formated style? You will also need to make those paragraphs a fixed-width font. Use hard line breaks is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Follow PEP-8 recomendations and keep lines < 80 characters.
Sometimes this seems very difficult or inconvenient. In these cases allow you up to 90-95 characters. Longer lines are probably the result of a bad design of the code or of wrongly selected variable names. (There is people working with standard sizes of up to 120 characters but probably they are not trying to publish the code in Word in portrait mode).

2) Use a monospaced font

3) Keep font size small enough to provide 80-95 characters per line.

Comment: I posted this question 2 years ago and never picked a correct answer (I did not know StackOverflow etiquette). So I am picking this one now as this is what I ended up doing. I basically just kept all my statements less than 80 characters, and copying and pasting into word seemed to work out alright. Mind you, I spent many hours going through all my scripts reformatting them like this and rerunning them to test if I had introduced any bugs :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Word to draft a plain-text document?  You can always convert it later.

Comment: jathanism, I do not understand what you mean. I am under the impression a plain-text document has no formatting in place. Either way  I will have to manually do all the level 1, 2, 3 indents for all the snippets. And then if I change the font size/style at a later time all the indents will likely getI will later have to make changes to font size and style, whether it is in plain text or in .docx and code indentation will probably not stay unchanged when this happens. Also the majority of the non-code text has already been typed out and is formatted and behaving well. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in a Python-enabled code editor with syntax highlight.  Save your snippets.  Take screenshots.  Paste them into MS Word.  Resize and crop the images as desired.

Now all you have to do is fight MS Word on the word-wrapping around images, which is a fight you might even win.

Comment: MadKeithV, I was avoiding using images since we are talking in excess of 200 snippets over the 500 pages of word document. This will be a lot of images/screenshots to work with. Also I won't be able to change the font size in screenshots. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 1):

Use [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

Instead of fighting against MS-Word (and other WYSIWYG editors) it's far, far easier to use docutils.

1. Write your document in approximately plain text.  You'll use  RST markup which is very simple and lightweight.
2. Run the `rst2html.py` conversion to create nice-looking HTML pages from your source.
3. Run the `rst2latex.py` conversion to create LaTeX from your source.  There are a variety of tools that can produce PDF from the LaTeX.

In this case, the code snippets are handled perfectly every single time.  No work.

If you're writing something really big and complex, you should be using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for this.  It's an extension to docutils with even more cool markup features for code snippets.

Comment: SLott, Thanks for this. Ive never used docutils or latex before but the procedure you have described sounds straightforward. However the non-code text in my document is very well formatted, and everything is associated with font styles, even individual words in many sentences, so I might lose all of this work if I start over from plain text and read through all 500 pages again :( .. I will look into RST markup tho, maybe some of the non-code formatting can be preserved?  I will also consider sphinx as per your recommendation. Thank you.

Comment: @Gary: All of the *non-code formatting* can be preserved.  If it requires too many extension classes, consider this as a sign that you've over-designed your document.  But Sphinx uses rich semantic markup, and you can work out a mapping from the markup to the presentation fonts and styles.

Comment: SLott, this is great to know. I will definitely be giving this a shot over the weekend or next week. Thanks a lot for this. Will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use word, but in LibreOffice, you could just use paragraph formatting - create a new paragraph style for each level of indent (`pycode`, `pycode_indent1...`). Put all of the formatting you want (mono-spaced, no paragraph spacing, etc.) in the top-level style, and make the indented styles use it as a parent. Then just add appropriate indents to each of the child styles. This is basically the same idea as multi-depth bulleted list, without the bullets. Then select the appropriate indent paragraph style for each line (hint: you can select multiple non-contiguous lines using ctrl+mouse in LibreOffice).

Granted, this way you have to do it line-by line, which could be a big pain in the arse. But if might work if it's just a few snippets that are being problematic.